# how to get tfs build revision number and last changeset number

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I have to show build revision number and last changeset number in the footer of my webpage. I am building my application using tfs.

How can i get the revision number and last changeset number(after the build is completed) ?

Comment: which version of TFS?, the method has changed on TFS2013.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `Build number` using a Team Foundation Build environment variable: `TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`. For more information read the [Team Foundation Build environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx) article.

Comment: From that article I tried to use `TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION` and the TFS build fails. [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2nPTLLqF)'s the error I get.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method in your web application that loads one of the built assemblies and parses the File Version information and presents that in the footer.